# How to install PWA in Magento 2.4.4 in windows

Tags: graphql, pwa, pwa-studio, magento-2-commerce, magento2.4.4

I need to install PWA (Progressive Web Apps) in Magento 2.4.4. so can anyone have an idea about it,then please share with me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot (technically you can but shouldn't) since Magento is not supported on Windows. See https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/system-requirements.html#operating-systems-(linux-x86-64)

Comment: Thanks for sharing.